# Get jobject from jclass in JNI

Tags: java, java-native-interface, jnienv

I wonder if there is a way to get a jobject from a jclass?  We can get the jclass from the JNIEnv call GetObjectClass(object), but I can't find anywhere to get the jobject from jclass, the reverse.  In my implementation, I cache the jclass instance using the NewGlobalRef() function, but then in the new thread I need the jobject to look up the MethodID.  There is no way for me to get the jobject.  I ended up caching the jobject instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to do reverse mapping because the there is not 1 : 1 relation between classes and objects. `jclass` represents a type whereas `jobject` represents an instance.

So it is possible to get the `jclass` from an `jobject` because it means "Identify the type of the instance". But reverse operation is irrelevant. There might be more than one instance of a given type or there can be even no instance of given class.

If you need a call a non-static method later then you have to remember a reference to the `jobject`.

Comment: For my case, the jclass should be a reference to a jobject instance.  I initially got the jclass from the jobject instance, and so, I thought It should be able to do the reverse casting it back.  Like in C++, If I have a *pCBase and a *pCConcrete derived from CBase,I can do pCBase =(CBase*)pCConcrete and pCConcrete = (CConcrete*)pCBase.

Comment: Continuing from my previous comment.  (I accidentally hit the enter key).  What confusing to me is that to make a non-static method call, I need the jclass to get the methodID, but then to make the  method call, I need the jobject as one of the parameter.  I could not use just one or the other because the app would crash.  Now, I need to keep the jobject around and always have to call the GetObjectClass and then have to call the DeleteLocalRef to avoid the ref table from being filled.  If what you say is JNI behavior, then I am stuck with this.

Comment: jclass is not a reference to a jobject instance. jclass is an instance of the java class `Class`. There is such thing like jclass/Class in the C++. The closest C++ mechanism is typeid/type_info. It is not a JNI specific rule. It is a general OOP mechanism. You need to know an instance (the jobject) to call a non-static method and you need to know a type (the jclass) to call a static method. Java (and JNI as well) allow to get a type from an instance (class from object) but the reverse mapping is impossible (in any language I guess).